# How can I cut off my slow Windows local network without touching the Internet connection?

Tags: windows-7, networking, performance

I want to cut off my Microsoft local network connection, but not the Internet (http, https) one. Any solution - like the Firewall - is good. By saying this, I suppose there is something (like a port or a Windows service) to separate the two. I want to do this because my network access is constantly slow, I don't generally need local network access and I think it is affecting collateral services.

Comment: What exactly do you believe is a "Microsoft network" connection?

Comment: This question is difficult to understand. Please take a minute to [edit] this to be specific of what you are trying to do. Do not include ramblings about another question as it only clutters things up.

Comment: @CharlieRB more clear now?

Comment: Not really. We have no details about your network for us to be able to answer your question. What are you trying to accomplish; increase your Internet speed, speed up your computer, what?

Comment: @CharlieRB I am trying to disable the Windows local network, why I am doing this is not of your business :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About services, Windows network represented by "Server" and "Workstation" services. You can set it to start manually in Services.

UPD: Advanced firewall is good solution for powerfull computer, but for weak system stopping services can be more reasonable.

Comment: I don't find "Windows network" because ... my (work) system is French, but I stopped "Server" and "Explorateur d'ordinateurs" (C:\WINDOWS\System32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs). I will come back with results ASAP.

Comment: Workstation is "Station de travail" in French, but I cannot stop it  since it affects Netlogon which, I suppose, is needed for domain logon (this is happening at work).

Comment: I need more time to play around, nevertheless I will accept your answer before these ... cowboys won't take some other actions.

Answer (score 1):

Using a firewall which asks  to allow or deny for every connection is what you want.

I can recommend Sygate Personal Firewall , **if your OS is XP and Connection is bellow 1 MB**

http://www.filehippo.com/download_sygate_personal_firewall

I did not need to use something like that for a long time so i cant recommend a new firewall that works like it.

Comment: Thank you, Xentios! (don't start a dispute until you have the necessary reputation :D)

Comment: My OS is Windows 7, as seen in the tag.